# Flask get 'next' parameters for a 'POST' request

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

There is a login function which accepts the data from a POST request. But in this case the "next" query parameter is ignored. What is the alternative for accessing the "next" query parameter other than `request.args`??

Below given is my login function

```
@route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], endpoint='login')
def login(self):
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = check_login(email=request.form['email'], password=request.form['password'])
        if user:
           login_user(user)
           return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
        else:
           # something else
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [`values`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.values):

> A CombinedMultiDict with the contents of both form and args.

This way, no matter where your `next` was set, you'll be able to retrieve it:

```
@route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], endpoint='login')
def login(self):
    redirect_url = request.values.get('next', url_for('index'))
```